# Javascript: check what link has user left though

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have page with some links. My question is, how can I check what link has user left through and send it to server using AJAX? I already have that AJAX part, I just can't figure out that link click part.

Comment: You got the *AJAX* part ***before*** the click event part?! Have you  tried search for it? - this is really quite a common task, there's some nice simple [examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="whateverurl" onClick="callmyAJAX(); return true;" ...
```